# Is there any downside to flatten data model schema in NOSQL Mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, typescript, architecture, nosql

I'm using NodeJS and typescript and I'm making typing for my functions in order to get auto-completion.

Currently I have a schema like this for User entity

```
interface User {
  "_id": string
  "coach": {
    "businessCard": string
  }
  "firstname": string
}
```

I'm using a nested object for the coach property, but my question is : What's the point of doing this, behind the scene MongoDB create another object which is referenced in a 1-to-1 relationship.

1. This probably reduce performances
2. I'm having issue to type my function to restrict fields that can be targeted in typescript

Let's see with an example :

```
await this.client.collection<User>('User').findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: new ObjectID(userId) },
     {"coach.businessCard": "50"},
);
```

will update the nested object.

But this syntax would have worked the same way using

```
interface User {
  "_id": string
  "coach.businessCard": string
  "firstname": string
}
```

The difference is that now I can uniformly use one syntax which match the dot notation.

---

So what could be the advantage of using the first notation I gave compared to the second one which is flatten ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of using nested Document One-To-One-Relationship are as below:

**1.** It represents the connection between data fields. For example: to save the user address we need to take multiple fields like:

```
 -> Address line 1   
 -> Address line 2   
 -> Locality    
 -> Region    
 -> Postcode    
 -> Building    
 -> Sub-Building    
 -> etc.
```

With the One-To-One-Relation we can bind the related information in a single unit as below:

```
address: {
     Address line 1: String ,
     Address line 2: String,    
     Locality: String,    
     Region: String,    
     Postcode: Number,        
     Building: Number,
     Sub-Building: Number,
     etc: String
}
```

**2.** It is helpful while retrieving such information from the database. For example:

-> To fetch full address details I can project with a single key.

```
db.collection.find({},{ address: 1} )
```

-> To fetch specific address field I can project on that as well like below:

```
db.collection.find({},{ 'address.Locality': 1, 'address.Region': 1} )
```

Comment: - All right for the second argument, it's clearly nice :)
- For the first, I concede this is way more readable but with a good naming convention prefix we can avoid that, isn't ?

Thanks for your answer :) will see if someone has more informations that we could have missed and eventually a solution for my typings issue :)